# beatbox._beatbox.SoapFaultError: 'API_DISABLED_FOR_ORG' 'API_DISABLED_FOR_ORG: API is not enabled for this Organization or Partner'

Tags: soap-api

Is there anyway to check the API enabled checkbox in the free trial version of Salesforce?

Answer (score 0):

Free trail version of salesforce is being professional edition api is an add on feature there. You will not be able to enable that during your trial. You need to contact with salesforce team to get this feature enabled.

if you need to experiment api callout why don't you use a [developer edition](https://developer.salesforce.com/signup) which is free and holds api access.